# Is request permission require for using PHPickerViewController & UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, phphotolibrary, phpickerviewcontroller

I have some confusion about permission with using `PHPickerViewController` & `UIImagePickerController`.

**Do I have to request permission for using it ? (Currently, I open it without request permission but It's working.)**

**Is it acceptable for upload to app store ? and if it acceptable when I have to request permission for photo?**

Ps.
I use `PHPickerViewController` for iOS14+ and `UIImagePickerController` for <iOS13.
Thank you for every reply or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know is, according to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller)

> The `PHPickerViewController` class is an alternative to `UIImagePickerController`. `PHPickerViewController` improves stability and reliability, and includes several benefits to developers and users

So both `PHPickerViewController` and `UIImagePickerController` are just the same with new upgrade.

As default, it runs in a separate process and on read-only access you don't need any special permissions for that.

And of course if you need some **advance features**, like retrieving assets and collections, or updating the library from your apps you must have permission for it.

You can read more from this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/delivering_an_enhanced_privacy_experience_in_your_photos_app) for permission to access some feature if need.

Comment: Thank you so much @bewithyou So clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHPicker provides a better privacy and does not require to ask for user consent so it can be used. Even though an app can trigger its presentation, the picker runs in a separate process where users can select only type of media necessary for their tasks, and do nothing beyond that; not even to get a snapshot of the picker. So, with PHPicker, simply forget about usage descriptions and rely on the built-in iOS privacy.

And if you want to explicitly allow user to select limited photos then you can implement it using the same.

**Yes there is no problem to upload it to the app store.**